# how to select anchor with class name in it

Tags: html, css, selenium

I am trying to automate testing for my webpage. on webpage, I need to select an anchor with a class name and text. the anchor is enclosed in a div element.

```html
<div class="margins0300">
<a tabindex="-32768" class="buttonLinkText">Hilfe</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to access `<a>` with `Selenium` internet explorer webdriver but not able to. here is my code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class,'buttonLinkText') and .//text()='Hilfe']"));
```

but when I execute it, no element is found.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're passing syntax as `xpath` while try to find element using `By.CssSelector()` which is wrong. You should try using `By.Xpath()` as below :-

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[@class = 'buttonLinkText' and text() = 'Hilfe']"));
```

You can also find this element using `By.LinkText()` as below :-

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Hilfe"));
```

**Edited** :- If you're still unable to find this element try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element exists as below :-

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Xpath("//a[@class = 'buttonLinkText' and text() = 'Hilfe']")));
```

**Note** :- Make sure this element is not inside any `frame/iframe`. If it is you need to switch that `frame/iframe` before finding element as :-

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame/iframe name or id");

//Now find the element using above code

//After doing all stuff inside frame/iframe you need to switch back to default content 
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Comment: I tried all possibilities; the one you posted as well but it did not work too.

Comment: @Shakti saxena What do you mean Didn't work?? Is there any exception??

Comment: yup. the same. element not found exception.

Comment: @Shakti saxena Then you need to implement WebDriverWait to wait until it exists, try with edited answer and let me know..:)

Comment: @@Shakti saxena and also make sure this element is not inside any `frame/iframe`

Comment: what if it is ?

Comment: If it is you need to switch that frame before finding element as `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame/iframe name or id")`

Answer (score 0):

That's how I found the answer because div element was enclosed in a frame and as per input from @saurabhgaur:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://websunp8.bk.datev.de/zws/ShowMenu.do");
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame("content");

  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class = 'buttonLinkText'  and text() = 'Hilfe']")).Click();
```

Comment: You can also use `driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Hilfe")).Click();` instead